# Listing Windows Server 2008 Enterprise local User Accounts without logging in

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-accounts

I have a Windows Server 2008 Enterprise installation on a server and I cannot remember the local user-accounts or passwords, so I'm unable to log in to the server. (This server was not been used for a while). Is there anyway that I can list the local user-account names without logging in?

Answer (score 0):

You could use tools like ERD Commander, however I'm not sure whether it works with W2K8